# How to mount a Kinect with my laptop without any AC Adapter

Tags: ros, kinematics, kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi team,

I would like to use Kinect without any AC Adapter. Turtlebot use use energy from roomba, but I would like to use other platform to navigate so I need to learn something similar to this image:

[image description http://www.hessmer.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/KinectOnRobot.jpg](http://www.hessmer.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/KinectOnRobot.jpg)

*http://www.hessmer.org*

Does anyone any reference to give energy to Kinect?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9868/how-to-mount-a-kinect-with-my-laptop-without-any-ac-adapter/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizz](https://answers.ros.org/users/34115/rizz/) on 2018-03-13**:
Notes,
I have seen it stated in a university tutorial that the kinect will operate reliably down to 8V,
This could alow regulated power from a 12v battery,
Haven't tried it myself.
The original turtlebot power gyro board uses a regulator with a enable pin to alow turning it off for charging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what voltage battery you have I suggest getting a linear voltage regulator. You should not hook the power cable from the kinect directly to the battery, you will get variations in voltage which will break your kinect. This tutorial will show you how to wire up a voltage regulator for a kinect, make sure to buy a voltage regulator that will down convert from you battery voltage, and then connect the power side pigtail to your battery: [Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20Kinect%20to%20an%20iRobot%20Create).

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need 12V Power from somewhere.

Take the kinect splitter cable and cut the part connected to the power supply.
The safest way is to measure the voltage to determine which is positive in case yours has different cabling then ours. For ours there is a brown and a light-grey cable inside, where brown is +12V.

It might be a good idea to put a plug in between so you can connect the kinect to either the on-board power source or the original power supply.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not an answer, but a warning.

A 12v lead-acid battery of that size has the strength to literally melt your face. The amperage it can put out makes it very dangerous. It is likely able to spot weld metal if you drop something across the contacts, and poses an explosion hazard. If you don't know what you're doing with soldering/wiring/managing power, do not learn with trial and error.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with these things, but please, be safe :)

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-02**:
Upvote for face-melting.  Somebody dropped a wrench across the terminals of one of our batteries (12V, 32Ah).  Needless to say, that wrench doesn't exist anymore.  The terminals on the battery aren't in good shape either.  Always pay attention!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tutorial on the Adept/Mobile Robots wiki on [how to mount a Kinect on a Pioneer robot](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Kinect_on_a_Pioneer_Mobile_Robot_with_Onboard_SBC).

The concept is essentially the same here, except you should at the very least a voltage regulator between your battery and the sensor. In fact, all power used by your robot should probably be regulated. Since the Pioneer robots already have a dedicated power board with that and more, that isn't mentioned in the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to use the Asus Xtion sensor.

It only needs USB power.

---

Originally posted by [Sven Behnke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4059/sven-behnke/) with karma: 43 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [busov](https://answers.ros.org/users/100966/busov/) on 2022-07-10**:
the kinect can be purchased for 20 $ at a pawn shop while the xtion is 400$ online!